# adding row and then deleting causes duplicate rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

So when I add new rows each row is given an id that increments according the number of rows already added.  if I add three rows and then delete the second row, then add another row, now the new row has an id the same as the old third row.

is there an easier way to do this or a loop that i can perform to check for an existing number.

```
$('body').delegate('.remove', 'click', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});

function addnewrow() {
  var n = ($('.detail tr').length - 0) + 1;
  var tr = '<tr>' +
    '<td>' + n + '</td>' +
    '<td><select id="drop' + n + '" class="select-service" name="prodService[]">  <
    option value = "" > -Choose Service - < /option></select > < /td>'+
  '<td id="desc' + n + '"></td>' +
    '<td><a href="#" class="remove">Delete</a></td>' +
    '</tr>';
```

Comment: why not just put counter outside of the function and just add one each time you create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery is nice because you can avoid writing these giant element strings, so I've gone ahead and rewritten your `addnewrow()` function to (hopefully) make it slightly cleaner.

As far as determining the IDs, while I believe what talg123 suggested in the comments would be fine - storing a global variable that just increases by 1 each time you add a new row - I personally try to avoid polluting the global scope where I can.

You can use this line to find the last `drop` id, and remove the `"drop"` text from it so you're just left with a number.

```
$("tr select").last().attr("id").replace("drop", "");
```

Unfortunately, this will break if there are no rows becuase it won't be able to find any `select` elements. So, first we have to check if they exist:

```
+$("tr select").length ? (exists) : (does not exist)
```

If it doesn't exist, we'll just use `1`.

Put that all together, and you've got:

```
//If select exists      Get last ID and remove "drop" from it, and add 1       Else, 1
$("tr select").length ? 1 + +$("tr select").last().attr("id").replace("drop", "") : 1;
```

```js
$('body').on("click", '.remove', function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});

$('body').on('click', '.add-new-row', function() {
  var nextId = $("tr select").length ? 1 + +$("tr select").last().attr("id").replace("drop", "") : 1;

  //Create a new select list
  var $selectList = $("<select id='drop" + nextId + "' class='select-service' name='prodService[]' />");
  $selectList.append("<option> -Select Service- </option"); //Append option 1
  $selectList.append("<option> Another example </option");  //Append option 2

  var $tr = $("<tr />");                                          //Create a new table row
  var $td1 = $("<td />").text(nextId).appendTo($tr);              //Create first cell. Set text to nextId. Add it to the row.
  var $td2 = $("<td />").append($selectList).appendTo($tr);       //Create second cell. Add our select list to it. Add it to the row.
  var $td3 = $("<td id='desc" + nextId + "' />").appendTo($tr);   //Create third cell. Set its id to 'desc{nextId}'. Add it to the row.
  var $td4 = $("<td />").append("<a href='#' class='remove'>Delete</a>").appendTo($tr);  //Create fourth cell. Add link to it. Add it to the row.

  $("table").append($tr);   //Add the row to the table
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="add-new-row">Add New Row</button>

<table></table>
```

Comment: i like this and thank you.  however i'm trying to add in a option with the text -Select Service- and can't figure that out.   while it answers my question and you put the time in to help, so thanks.  i have go with something i know how to edit.

Comment: @MichaelSickler Please take a look at my edited code. I've separated out your select list. You can use `.append` to add new options - I've added two as an example.

Comment: Also added some comments to hopefully document the process a bit more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way...Put counter outside of the function.

```js
$('body').on("click", '.remove', function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
var n = 1;
$('body').on('click', '.add-new-row', function() {
  
  var $tr = $("<tr />");
  var $td1 = $("<td />").text(n).appendTo($tr);
  var $td2 = $("<td />").append("<select id='drop" + n + "' class='select-service' name='prodService[]' />").appendTo($tr);
  var $td3 = $("<td id='desc" + n + "' />").appendTo($tr);
  var $td4 = $("<td />").append("<a href='#' class='remove'>Delete</a>").appendTo($tr);

  $("table").append($tr);
  n++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="add-new-row">Add New Row</button>

<table></table>
```